# How would you implement a fast lookup by multiple keys?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I am looking to create a fast lookup (dictionary?) with optional keys so for example, let's say I have 3 keys: "first_name", "last_name", "zipcode"

so I would like to be able to do the following (pseudocode):

```
GetValue(first_name) -- would return a list of everyone with that first name
GetValue(first_name, last_name) -- would return a list of everyone with that first name & last name
GetValue(zipcode, first_name) -- would return a list of everyone with that first_name in the specified zipcode
```

I should be able to query out all permutations of those keys. What data structure would you use for this? How would you implement this?

Comment: Dictionary has a single key.   What you are looking for is called a database.

Comment: Can you have a dictionary of dictionaries?

Comment: @Paparazzi: I don't want to make a request to the database all the time. I would like to cache out the data into some structure so I can query it from my cache.

Comment: if your collection is less than 1000 items, it really doesn't matter. put your data inside a list and then make your queries on that using LINQ

Comment: @AshkanSirous - the collection is over 10,000 items and the code is making too many queries on it which is why I am thinking of optimizing it.

Comment: OH, you don't *want* to call a database.  So you are going create a multi-key lookup yourself.  Good luck.

Comment: You could consider a B-Tree.

Comment: @Denis For any given first name are there more than 1000 items with that first name?  If not, just make the dictionary based on first name and then do a linear search through the list it returns.

Comment: @Kyle: I don't know if sub-dictionaries would work because I would be making assumptions about my data which isn't correct and this search wouldn't be optimal if you don't start a search with the top element like "first name" (in your example)

Comment: @Denis In your example all your queries required the first name.  If that's not appropriate you should clarify the sorts of queries you expect to make.

Comment: Will multiple threads access it? Really, for your case `List<Person>` should be enough. It is not like you have a million rows. And Linq-to-objects. `myList.Where(x=>x.Firstname==. . . . )` will suffice. And lists are safe to iterate by multiple threads and you can also make it `AsReadOnly`. It is working - I have in my current web system - 50 tables are cached and largest has 10-15K rows. Our system used to query DB 300 times each request, now it is 20-30

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could still use regular dictionaries where the key could be a custom type like this:

```
public class CompositeKey
{
     public CompositeKey(string firstName, string lastName, string zipCode)
     {
           FirstName = firstName;
           LastName = lastName;
           ZipCode = zipCode;
     }

     public string FirstName { get; }
     public string LastName { get; }
     public string ZipCode { get; }
}
```

Now I would override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` on `CompositeKey` to provide what makes a composite key unique so `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` would be able to store unique composite keys.

Finally, I would be able to query the dictionary this way:

```
var value = dict[new CompositeKey(firstName: "Matías", lastName: "Fidemraizer" )];
```

OP asked this question in some comment:

> I thought about this approach but how would you query the dictionary
>   for "FirstName = "Matias" only?

Since you're overriding both `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, you can add all combinations as keys in the whole dictionary and they can all co-exist there:

```
Person person = new Person { /* Set members here */ }

// Note that I'll add many keys that have the same value
dict.Add(new CompositeKey(name: "Matías"), person);
dict.Add(new CompositeKey(lastName: "Fidemraizer"), person);
dict.Add(new CompositeKey(firstName: "Matías", lastName: "Fidemraizer"), person);
```

Each key will result in a different hash code so they can all co-exist in the same dictionary and they will provide a powerful tool to query by many criterias and criteria combinations.

### Another approach

Other approach could be using multiple dictionaries where their keys are concatenations of the whole values using some convention and the values are instances of the whole class:

```
Dictionary<string, Person> names = new Dictionary<string, Person>();
names.Add("matias", new Person { /* Set members here */ });

Dictionary<string, Person> names = new Dictionary<string, Person>();
names.Add("matias:fidemraizer", new Person { /* Set members here */ });

// And so on, for every criteria you want to search...
```

Later you would implement a proxy to determine what dictionary to query based on the given criteria.

### What about Redis

Actually you should take a look at [Redis](http://redis.io), which is a key-value store with complex data structures as values like hashes, sets, sorted sets and many more. That is, you could centralize your cache and distribute it using Redis, and you cache could be consumed by many applications.

It's extremely simple to use and install (it's an executable of less than 10MB...).

### @Paparazzi has raised an issue with the dictionary approach

He has said:

> What about a second person with the same first name?

If OP would need to consider this case (yes, it's not an exceptional case, so it's worth the effort to consider it!), it seems like OP would need to store data in a dictionary where keys are the whole *composite keys* and values should be `List<Person>`, `HashSet<Person>` or even `LinkedList<Person>`.

Furthermore, this would mean that one *key* (slot) would be able to store many persons, and a query like *get a person with first name* `"Matías"` would always return an implementation of `IEnumerable<Person>` (list, hash, linkedlist...), where the whole returned collection would be *found persons*:

```
KeyValuePair<CompositeKey, ISet<Person>> result;

if(dictionary.TryGetValue(new CompositeKey(firstName: "Matías"), out result))
{
    // I've got either one or many results and I'll decide what to do in
    // that case!
}
```

Also, this enhanced approach has another possible issue. When you query with a composite key like `new CompositeKey(firstName: "Matías")` and the whole dictionary store could have stored more than a person with `"Matías"` first name,  you'll get an `ISet<Person>`, `IList<Person>` or `LinkedList<Person>`.

The first search to get one or many results has a complexity `O(1)` (constant time) because the whole composite key is stored based on its *hash code*, **but the returned result of the first search isn't a dictionary anymore and any search against them is going to be O(N) (*the more items you get, the more time is taken to find a result*)**.

BTW, if you're trying to find a person by its first name, **it's because you know that you can get more than a result and you can't expect to find one unless only one person with the whole first name has been stored in the dictionary**.

So it seems that you'll need to disambiguate results if their count is greater than `1`, and this can be done either performing another `O(1)` search by providing a composite key with more than the *first name*, or some **human user** (or artificial intelligence...) will need to manually choose one of the results.

In summary:

- If you look for a person by providing one component, you're taking the risk of getting more than a result. Then, if it's an application with UI or some kind of artificial intelligence, there should happen no search at all, but choice an item from the result directly (which is an operation with `O(1)` complexity):

```
KeyValuePair<CompositeKey, ISet<Person>> result;

if(dictionary.TryGetValue(new CompositeKey(firstName: "Matías"), out result))
{
    if(result.Value.Count > 1)
    {
         // Here you would show the user what you've found in the UI
         // and the whole user would choose one of the results directly,
         // which is an operation with O(1) complexity 
    }
    else if(result.Value.Count <= 1)
    {
         // OK, I got 0 or 1 result, this is easier than I thought! ;)
    }
}
```

- If you look for a person by providing one component, and once your application realizes that it got more than a result it can automatically provide another component, **you won't perform a search against the result, but you'll provide a new composite key providing more components against the main dictionary and luckily, you'll get a single result.**

```
public KeyValuePair<CompositeKey, ISet<Person>> SearchPerson(CompositeKey key)
{
    KeyValuePair<CompositeKey, ISet<Person>> result;

    if(dictionary.TryGetValue(new CompositeKey(firstName: "Matías"), out result))
    {
        if(result.Value.Count > 1)
        {
            // Oops! More than one result..... BUT I already know another 
            // component that will make the whole key absolutely unique, so
            // I'll call this method recursively to specialize the search even
            // more. Obviously, I've hardcoded the ZIP code as a sample, but
            // in a real-world case, who knows from where I would get this 
            // ZIP code... Maybe from some geolocalization query based on current
            // user's location?
            // Wait, it might happen that a person called Matías could live
            // in a location near be so this other person would have stored
            // the same ZIP code... Well, this goes outside the scope of this
            // Q&A. It's just an example of what to do, in an actual application
            // there should be many other choices to disambiguate persons
            // automatically...
            return SearchPerson(new CompositeKey(firstName: key.FirstName, zipCode: "03984"));

        }
        else if(result.Value.Count <= 1)
        {
             // OK, I got 0 or 1 result, this is easier than I thought! ;)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought about this approach but how would you query the dictionary for "FirstName = "Matias" only?

Comment: @Denis It's even easier than you thought.... Since I'm suggesting you that you should override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, what prevents you from adding multiple keys with a limited number of key components and as value storing the same instance?

Comment: Because you can only hash to one number so if a user has both a zipcode and lastname using one of them wont give you the proper hash

Comment: @AlexKrupka Obviously both approaches aren't the most powerful indexing methodologies, but they can solve OP's simple scenario. If he queries using typed composite keys, key component order won't matter. This problem arises with the second approach, which should be also enough on OP's case, while the first one is the most powerful one in the long term...

Comment: @AlexKrupka I've double-checked your comment. I'm not sure what you're saying. If you've the same person indexed in the whole dictionary, with multiple keys, what prevents you from querying by name, last name, zip code, some of them or all of them?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I commented before the response to Denis'scomment I though you were suggesting somehow to have multiple permutaions of fields that hash to the same hash. In essence, never mind.

Comment: @AlexKrupka Oh I see, ok! ;)

Comment: @Denis See my updates on the answer. I believe that now you should be in the right track!

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: This was great! Thank you!

Comment: What about a second person with the same first name?

Comment: @Paparazzi Clearly we would need to store the whole persons on a dictionary like this: `Dictionary<CompositeKey, List<Person>>` or even `Dictionary<CompositeKey, LinkedList<Person>>`. Thus, many partial keys could be stored in the same *slot* and you would get one or more results...

Comment: @Paparazzi I've edited my answer to solve your concern. Let me know if it's fine now :)

Comment: So the person needs to be stored mulitple times?  Then search the list is O(N).  Not liking this.

Comment: @Paparazzi Search it's not O(N). It's near to O(1). There's nothing wrong with storing one person with 1k keys, it'll be still O(1) because if you want it by his/her first name, you'll obtain it using the hash code. BTW, another story is when you want to retrieve a person by *first name* **when there could happen more than a coincidence**. The search for the slot containing all coincidences is O(1) and once you get to the coincidence set, it's O(1) against a small number of persons.

Comment: @Paparazzi BTW, if you query by the first name, and could happen more than a coincidence, you can't point to a single person, I guess that some UI would show all possible coincidences and user would select one and this retrieval would be also O(1)...

Comment: @Paparazzi At the end of the day, you need some disambiguation approach, but if you just know a component of a composite key, once you've realized that you got many results, you'll need to provide some other component to locate a concrete person.................

Comment: @Paparazzi I've re-updated my answer to explain this with more detail... Let me know if I've convinced you or not ;D

Comment: Let it go. I am not keen with this approach.  I would use an in memory database.

Comment: @paparazzi I've already suggested Redis. BTW since OP was looking for a pure .net solution with data structures... I tried to do my best on this

Comment: @paparazzi BTW with Redis you would need to go through a similar route....

Comment: I am not criticizing your answer.  I am not keen on the question either.  It seems like an artificial constraint.

Comment: @Paparazzi Oh don't worry, I like discussing ;) Yeah, I'm with you, BTW the question is interesting for future readers because most developers don't take advantage of hashed collections

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120335/discussion-between-paparazzi-and-matias-fidemraizer).

Answer (score 3):

You can use 3 `Lookup`s :

```
var FirstNamesLookup = data.ToLookup(x => Tuple.Create(x.FirstName), x => x);
var FirstAndLastLookup = data.ToLookup(x => Tuple.Create(x.FirstName, x.LastName), x => x);
var FirstAndZipLookup = data.ToLookup(x => Tuple.Create(x.FirstName, x.zipCode), x => x);
```

All records with certain FirstName:

```
var matches = FirstNamesLookup[Tuple.Create("SomeName")].ToList();
```

All records with certain FirstName and LastName:

```
var matches = FirstAndLastLookup[Tuple.Create("SomeName", "SomeLastName")].ToList();
```

Same goes for the third case.

Comment: Using anonymous type would be better than `Tuple.Create`.

Comment: @Xiaoy312 unless you want to pass these `lookup`s around.

Comment: Right, that would screw up everything. C# 7.0 should fix this with the new [language support for tuple](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/1936/c-sharp-7-0-features/6329/language-support-for-tuples#t=201608041844521344757)

Comment: @Xiaoy312 No need you can return `ILookup<Tuple<string,string>, List<SomeClass>>` . It is not neat but it works. However, you can't do that we anonymous types. Tuples are used here for the advantage of automatic equality.

Answer (score 1):

You should just use any generic collection type, and use LINQ to do the lookup :

```
var addresses = Enumerable.Empty<Address>();

// would return a list of everyone with that first name
addresses.Where(x => x.FirstName == "firstname");

// would return a list of everyone with that first name & last name
addresses.Where(x => x.FirstName == "firstname" && x.LastName == "lastname");

// would return a list of everyone with that first_name in the specified zipcode
addresses.Where(x => x.FirstName == "firstname" && x.ZipCode == "zipcode");
```

Comment: but wouldn't this be a scan of all the data? Suppose there is a lot of data and a LINQ scan would take forever.

Comment: You have to scan through them anyways. If you do care about performance on multiple access, you can always cache a lookup index with to `ToLookUp()`.

Comment: the ToLookup() would have been great but I just remembered this is old code still running using .NET 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Based on all the ideas here and the fact that I was constrained to using .NET 2.0 I did it like this. Including it just for completeness in case someone comes across this problem again. [Won't mark this as answer because it is based on a lot of ideas from @Matias above so marking his as the answer that contributed the most to the ultimate solution]:

```
public class PersonKey {
    public string FirstName { get; private set; }
    public string LastName { get; private set; }
    public int Zipcode { get; private set; }

    public PersonKey() {
        FirstName = null;
        LastName = null;
        Zipcode = int.MinValue;
    }

    public PersonKey(int Zipcode, string FirstName) : this() {
        this.FirstName = FirstName;
        this.Zipcode = Zipcode;
    }

    public PersonKey(string LastName, string FirstName) : this() {
        this.FirstName = FirstName;
        this.LastName = LastName;
    }

    public PersonKey(int Zipcode, string LastName, string FirstName) {
        this.Zipcode = Zipcode;
        this.LastName = LastName;
        this.FirstName = FirstName;
    }

    public List<string> KeyList {
        get {
            var keyLst = new List<string>();
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstName))
                keyLst.Add("FirstName:" + FirstName);

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(LastName))
                keyLst.Add("LastName:" + LastName);

            if (Zipcode != int.MinValue)
                keyLst.Add("Zipcode:" + Zipcode);

            return keyLst;
        }
    }

    public string Key {
        get {
            return MakeKey(KeyList.ToArray());
        }
    }

    public List<string[]> AllPossibleKeys {
        get {
            return CreateSubsets(KeyList.ToArray());
        }
    }

    List<T[]> CreateSubsets<T>(T[] originalArray) {
        List<T[]> subsets = new List<T[]>();

        for (int i = 0; i < originalArray.Length; i++) {
            int subsetCount = subsets.Count;
            subsets.Add(new T[] { originalArray[i] });

            for (int j = 0; j < subsetCount; j++) {
                T[] newSubset = new T[subsets[j].Length + 1];
                subsets[j].CopyTo(newSubset, 0);
                newSubset[newSubset.Length - 1] = originalArray[i];
                subsets.Add(newSubset);
            }
        }

        return subsets;
    }

    internal string MakeKey(string[] possKey) {
        return String.Join(",", possKey);
    }
```

and then I create a cache like this:

```
//declare the cache
        private Dictionary<string, List<Person>> _lookup = new Dictionary<string, List<Person>>();
```

when I read a record from the database I store it in the cache like this:

```
  var key = new PersonKey(person.ZipCode, person.LastName, person.FirstName);
  List<Person> lst;
  foreach (var possKey in key.AllPossibleKeys) {
      var k = key.MakeKey(possKey);
      if (!_lookup.TryGetValue(k, out lst)) {
           lst = new List<Person>();
           _lookup.Add(k, lst);
      }
      lst.Add(person);
   }
```

Looking up from the cache is pretty straightforward:

```
  List<Person> lst;
  var key = new PersonKey(lastName, firstName);  //more constructors can be added in PersonKey
   _lookup.TryGetValue(key.Key, out lst);
```

Comment: Yeah, that's it! To be honest, when I started to use Redis 2 years ago or so, I realized how simple data structures could be adapted to store complex use cases and how using simple data structures could outperform nice looking ones like using LINQ or even SQL. Obviously there're use cases where LINQ or SQL are better, but your case is a good example of what I'm saying on this comment ;P